# Not able to call onchange and onclick JavaScript functions from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript function to choose the selected option to chnage the content of a table cell :

```
<script>
function getValue(selValue) {
if(selValue == "Apple")
    document.getElementById("fruittype").innerHTML = "A";

if(selValue == "Banana")
    document.getElementById("fruittype").innerHTML = "B";

if(selValue == "Orange")
    document.getElementById("fruittype").innerHTML = "C";
}
</script>
```

And below is my php function that I am calling :

```
<?php
function retainFormOnLoad($fruit)
{           
    echo "<form d='form1' name='form1' method='post' >";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
        <td>Congress Database</td> 
        <td style='text-align: center;'>
        <select name='fruit' id='fruit' onchange='getValue(document.getElementById('fruit').value)'>
            <option value='-1' selected disabled>Select your option</option>
            <option value='Apple' ".(($fruit=='Apple')?'selected':'')." >Apple</option>
            <option value='Banana' ".(($fruit=='Banana')?'selected':'')." >Banana</option>
            <option value='Orange' ".(($fruit=='Orange')?'selected':'')." >Orange</option>              
        </select>
     </td>
  </tr>";
  echo "<tr>
     <td id='fruittype'>A</td>
     <td>Always Good!</td>
  </tr>";
 echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='reset' value='Clear' onclick='reset()'></td></tr>
</table></form>";
}
?>
```

When I call the above function, the default values of form fields are set but the `onchange` and `onclick` javascript functions do not work. Where am I going wrong? Please help

(***And I have to use PHP only to echo the form)

Comment: Where does php run?  Where does javascript run?

Comment: `onchange='getValue(document.getElementById('fruit').value)'` ,,, the problem is with `'` you need the output to look more like `onchange='getValue(document.getElementById("fruit").value)'` , so you'll need to escape the `"` around `fruit` in php

Comment: or, better still `onchange='getValue(this.value)'` - then you wont need to do the escape-quote shuffle at all